# Setting outer class variable from anonymous inner class

Tags: java, android

Hey guys i am trying to export data from a third party app and then set the path of resulting exported file to my textview in main activity.But it isn't working.I searched all over and came to a conclusion that it has something to do with anonymous class,but i am still not able to fix it.Can anyone please guide me.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Button btRecieve = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btRecieve);

    final Context context = this.getApplicationContext();

    final TextView tvFilePath = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvFilepath);
    final TextView tvFeedBack = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvFeedBack);

    final String pDateFrom = "2012-07-01";
    final String pDateTo = "2012-07-06";
    final String pExportType = "e5";
    final String pExportFormat = "csv";

    btRecieve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TimeRecordingExport exporter = new TimeRecordingExport(pDateFrom,pDateTo,pExportType,pExportFormat,tvFilePath);
            exporter.Export(context);
            String path = exporter.getFilePath();

            tvFilePath.setText(path);


        }
    });
}
}







public class TimeRecordingExport{
   //private variables
   String mDateFrom;
   String mDateTo;
   String mExportType;
   String mExportFormat;

   private String mFilepath;                     //path to the output file
   String feedback;

   TextView mTv;

   File file;

   Context mContext;

   final String KEY_RESULT_FILE = "com.dynamicg.timerecording.FILE";



//Constructor
   public TimeRecordingExport(String pDateFrom,String pDateTo,String pExportType,String pExportFormat,TextView tv){

     //Initialize private variables
     mDateFrom = pDateFrom;
     mDateTo = pDateTo;
     mExportFormat = pExportFormat;
     mExportType = pExportType;
     mTv = tv;

   }    //End constructor

   //Export function
   public void Export(Context pContext){
       mContext = pContext;
       //create a new intent with action export
       Intent intent = new Intent("com.dynamicg.timerecording.DATA_EXPORT");

       //Add extra values or you could say parameters to this intent.
       intent.putExtra("com.dynamicg.timerecording.DATE_FROM",mDateFrom);
       intent.putExtra("com.dynamicg.timerecording.DATE_TO",mDateTo);
       intent.putExtra("com.dynamicg.timerecording.EXPORT_TYPE",mExportType);
       intent.putExtra("com.dynamicg.timerecording.EXPORT_FORMAT",mExportFormat);

       //make a broadcast reciever
       BroadcastReceiver resultReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
           @Override
           public void onReceive(Context context, Intent resultIntent) {

               Bundle bundle = this.getResultExtras(true);
               TimeRecordingExport.this.mFilepath = bundle.getString(KEY_RESULT_FILE);               //Path to the created file
               //mTv.setText(mFilepath[0]);
               file = new File(mFilepath);                                                           //New Created file

               feedback = "File=["+file+"], canRead=["+file.canRead()                                //Info about the created file
                       +"], sizeKB=["+(file.length()/1024)+"]";
               //Toast.makeText(mContext, feedback, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               Toast.makeText(context, feedback, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               System.out.println(feedback);
           }
       };
       mContext.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null, resultReceiver, null, Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
   } //End function export

   public String getFilePath(){

       return mFilepath;
   }

   public String getFileInfo(){
       return feedback;
   }

}   //End of class
```

Comment: not working means,textview doesnt show the path to file.It works when I place the texview.setText() inside anonymous class "Broadcastreciever".

Answer (score 0):

First, have you tried putting a test string in for the path value?  Just to be sure it's not your data?  Second, guess I've always defined my widgets as class variables of the Activity instead of final variables in the onCreate method.